# Blackberry - prevent ListField from scrolling after removing an item

Tags: blackberry, scroll, listfield

I have a ListField which is a long vertical list of items you can select and delete. Upon deleting an item, the list scrolls back to the top. I can use setSelectedIndex(rowIndex) to return to the spot in the list I had been viewing, but this will not preserve the rows I had been viewing on screen. Instead, the row appears at the bottom of the screen because it stopped scrolling once the correct index appeared on screen.

Is there a way I can remove a row and preserve my view/spot of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized I was using the wrong ListField.setSize() function.

ListField.setSize(int size) sends your focus back to the top of the list, but you can use ListField.setSize(int size, int focusRow) to leave the focus at "currentIndex" if you want. 
Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 1):

1. Save the current position in the list ( via `myListField.getSelectedIndex()` ), let say

   int myVar = myListField.getSelectedIndex();
2. Remove item
3. use `myVar`, and using current list size and `myVar` value calculate and set list index via `myListField.setSelectedIndex(int index);` Use another thread and `Application.invokeLater(Runnable thread);` for this action to avoid event locking issues upon updating UI of your application.

That's it.

Comment: This brings focus to the correct row, but the rows that are shown on screen would still be different. For example, I'm viewing rows 5-10, but after removeRow(8), setSelectedIndex(8) brings the screen to rows 3-8

Comment: I did not get what you exactly mean. If you wish to set focus to a particular object, find this object in the list when you have a row removed and set the focus to the found list index.